# Values of Existential Quantifiers in Z3

Tags: z3, smt, quantifiers

Say, I write a simple code with quantifiers as below:

```
from z3 import *
s = SolverFor("LIA")
x1, y1 = Ints('x1 y1')
s.add(ForAll(x1, Implies(x1>=0, Exists(y1, (y1>x1)))))
```

print(s.check())
print(s.model())

The result is :

```
sat
[ ]
```

Shouldn't this output a value of y1 for which it is satisfiable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what would that value be? Note that the value of `y1` depends on `x1` in your formula, so it wouldn't make sense to print `y1` only.

In general, once you go under a universal quantifier z3 can no longer print the value of variables. To do so meaningfully, it would have to print all the prefix universals, and unless all your domains are finite this wouldn't make sense. (Nor it would be useful.)

Comment: I agree to your point. But what will happen if the universal quantifier is under an existential quantifier? Will we get the values of the variables under the existential quantifier then?

Comment: Why don’t you try it and let us know what you find out! In general, prefix existentials can be pulled out to top level and thus you’ll get a value, even if it’s indirect.

Comment: Further note that the names of bound variables are not necessarily unique, so they would be hard to identify. The best solution to this problem is to skolemize the formula before handing it to Z3, then the Skolem functions can be named appropriately.